# How to compare differences on commit on a single file between 2 branches in Git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

A branch and B branch both have A, B, C, D commits and in B, C commits, file `xxx.java` is changed.

but A branch has E,F,G,H commits and in F, H commits, file `xxx.java` is changed.

Is there a command, after

`$git command xxx.java branchA branchB`

I can get:

```
F -- F commit id(for example, 1fd3bb10d0d8b63c20cf0b2aa0c6f92812cb7b7f)
H -- H commit id
```

( I don't need the difference in the specific content of the file, it's something that interferes and wants to be deleted )

And does IDEA have a visual tool for this situation?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you looking for `git log branchB..branchA -- xxx.java` ?

Comment: You can add other options to `git log` : `git log --graph --oneline branchB..branchA -- xxx.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just need a history of specific files across all branches. IntelliJ can show it for you - call Git | Show History on a file, and then enable the Show All Branches on the toolbar.
[image]